# convert a html page to jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, bootstrap-4

I have designed my interface using bootstrap. Now only I realised that I should have done it with JSP in order to connect with my backend done through Spring framework. Can anyone suggest me how to convert my HTML pages to JSP pages

Comment: You dont need to convert anything. Start a JSP project and copy-paste your HTML file into the JSP file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the file extension to jsp and add the jsp specific code you need. You will also need a controller for mapping if you don't already have one, but there are plenty of tutorials on the web.

Or there is thymeleaf which means you will not need to worry about jsp,
 this guide will help: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/